# Problem in porting Chicken of VNC Mac application into iphone application

Tags: iphone, macos, sockets, vnc, chicken-scheme

I'm porting **Chicken of VNC Mac application into iphone application**

I am having source code of Chicken of VNC Mac application which take vnc of any LAN connected mac. I have to do same with iphone app. So while debugging mac source code I am not able to figure out how that mac app establish an authenticated VNC connection?

**My Current Progress**
I have done some progress. Now i am able to connect any LAN connected MAC and can take VNC of it. But i think the way i am doing is wrong. Actually now i am calling unstoppable timer again & again for [conn startTalking] and making RFBConnection with server on every mseconds for uninterrupted connection. Is this is a right way ? But this arise a new problem i cannot scroll my vnc view because on every mseconds screen is refreshing with new RFBConnection. Can any one guide me ?

> **Its pretty strange that none of experts are sharing their views on
>   this thread**

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question: how to store/retrieve passwords in iOS’ keychain, how to store/retrieve passwords in Mac OS X’ keychain, or how does the application you’re porting deals with passwords?

Comment: Yes my question is how the application deals with password. How they will send information to make connection established. I am having source code of Chicken of VNC Mac application which take vnc of any LAN connected mac. I have to do same with iphone app. So while debugging mac source code I am not able to figure out how they are sending information for connection establish.

Comment: So your question is **not** about password storage and retrieval but instead how to establish an authenticated VNC connection?

Comment: chicken-scheme is a wrong tag for this. [CHICKEN Scheme is a programming language](https://call-cc.org).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See section 7.1 (handshaking messages) and 7.2 (security types) of [this page describing the RFB protocol](http://tigervnc.org/cgi-bin/rfbproto).

Comment: I have done good progress, now I am able to take vnc of any machine connected to LAN but it works only for 2 seconds. As soon as I launch application it take vnc for 2 seconds and then suddenly screen got black screen. Can you guide me ?

Comment: @Tariq, I only really know the VNC protocol. I have not done iPhone development. But I suggest you enable some debugging to figure out what's going on. Are you saying that you see the remote screen for 2 seconds or that after authentication, the screen goes black? What happens if you connect to the same server using Chicken of the VNC from OS-X?

Comment: I have done some progress. Now i am able to connect any LAN connected MAC. But i think the way i am doing is wrong. Actually now i am calling unstoppable timer again & again for [conn startTalking] and making RFBConnection with server on every mseconds for uninterrupted connection. Is this is a right way ? But this arise a new problem i cannot scroll my vnc view because on every mseconds screen is refreshing with new RFBConnection.

Comment: can you possibly share the project so that I can try to fix it please?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea. Porting an existing complex application to a platform you do not know is a recipe for failure. Build some simple iPhone apps first, so you get a good feeling for how things are done on the platform.

Did you start by making a list of all Mac Cocoa code in there that is not supported on Cocoa Touch? And then build replacements for all of them?

Comment: I don't have enough time to build up samples. I have very limited time to complete this project. And I have successfully connected to any LAN connected MAC. And able to take VNC of it. But refreshing rate creating problems. Thats why I asked my problem in stackoverflow. If you can suggest whats wrong with RFBConnection then it will be good.